# react-native-config - Unrecognized option alwaysOutOfDate

Tags: react-native, react-native-config

I get this error when I run `pod install`:

```
The `react-native-config` pod failed to validate due to 1 error:
    - ERROR | script_phases: Unrecognized option(s) `alwaysOutOfDate` in script phase `Config codegen`. 
Available options are `name, script, shell_path, input_files, output_files, input_file_lists, output_file_lists, show_env_vars_in_log, execution_position, dependency_file`.
```

---

- Xcode `14.0`
- react-native 0.67.1`
- react-native-config `1.4.6`

Answer (score 0):

Solved by removing the `^` before the version number in my `package.json`:

`"react-native-config": "1.4.6"`